# Nginx ldap auth login by different attributes

Tags: nginx

I need to configure nginx to sign in by two kinds dn :

```
cn=appname,ou=Applications,o=example.com
uid=username,ou=People,o=example.com
```

Here is piece of code for ldap server:

```
ldap_server ldapserver {
  url ldaps://ldap.example.com/o=example.com?uid,cn?sub?(..filter for search...)
}
```

However, only username can be signed in, appname can't.
But if I switch the position of uid and cn for that url, like

```
url ldaps://ldap.example.com/o=example.com?cn,uid?sub?(..filter for search...)
```

Then appname can be used to sign, username can't.

Is this nginx-ldap-auth's bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [source](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/blob/master/ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c#L1822), the module appears to currently be designed in this way; it'll just consider the first attribute in your comma-separated list even though the `ldap_url_parse` function (what the module uses under the hood) supports specifying multiple attributes.

I would add a feature request / issue at https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/issues.

In the meantime, you can use multiple `ldap_server` blocks to define two different configurations, one with one attribute and one with the other, such as:

```
ldap_server ldapserver_one {
    url ldaps://ldap.example.com/o=hp.com?uid?sub?(..filter for search...)
}
ldap_server ldapserver_two {
    url ldaps://ldap.example.com/o=hp.com?cn?sub?(..filter for search...)
}
location / {
    auth_ldap "Authorised Only";
    auth_ldap_servers ldapserver_one;
    auth_ldap_servers ldapserver_two;
    ...
}
```

It'll require making two separate connections to your LDAP server, but it'll work.

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried what you said. But if group restriction is introduced into this config, it doesn't work.  For example, if I add group restriction for ldapserver_one, then that restriction will never take effect.

Comment: @user2321728, I'd check your config; I have two servers setup with different configs, one for groups and one without, and both conditions are checked.  Try this for inspiration: https://gist.github.com/davidjb/5a2b0362b5b911ad6ab5